# MethodInfo always null when geting Type from instance

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

Can someone explain me, why here I get the correct `MethodInfo`:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(ContextTimerMode).GetMethod(_vo.Phase, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

if (mi != null)
{
    mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { btns, vo });
}
```

While trying to get it directly from instance returns always null?:

```
MethodInfo mi = (this as ContextTimerMode).GetType().GetMethod(_vo.Phase, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// mi always null
if (mi != null)
{
    mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { btns, vo });
}
```

The code above is from `ContextTimerMode`.

`this` is a class that has `ContextTimerMode` as base class;

Actually I couldn't find a reason why it returns a null for sometime as I was using second method and I was debugging and making sure `_vo.Phase` string has correct name of method so I tried first method and it worked out.

Also when debugging `this` was showing that `this` is instance not of `ContextTimerMode` but a type that has a base of `ContextTimerMode` - so that is why I tried with `(this as ContextTimerMode).GetType()`...

Comment: `typeof(T)` and `T.GetType()` **have to** be same type. Have you checked that in your case?

Comment: @dymanoid That would be good way to debug it, but I didn't thanks for info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because even if you do this:

```
(this as ContextTimerMode).GetType()
```

resulting type will *not* be `ContextTimerMode`, but will be the type inherited from `ContextTimerMode` (so, actual type of `this`, same as if you did `this.GetType()`). `GetType()` always returns actual type, even if you use it on variable declared as some base type. You are trying to get private, instance method of that type. Your inherited type really does not contain this method, so `GetMethod` correctly returns null.

If you want to work around this, you can manually walk hierarchy, like this:

```
static MethodInfo GetMethod(Type type, string methodName, BindingFlags flags) {
    var mi = type.GetMethod(methodName, flags);
    if (mi != null)
        return mi;
    if (type.BaseType != null)
        return GetMethod(type.BaseType, methodName, flags);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is redundant. You can just use GetType() internally and it will refer to your class.

```
_vo.Phase
```

must be the correct case and you don't need BindingFlags.Instance. I would remove BindingFlags.NonPublic as well and change the method access modifier to public to see if GetMethod() can actually find it.

You can always use GetMethods() to enumerate the available methods in the class. Maybe even use a linq query to get the MethodInfo object you want.